Process hang when using Silent InstallShield install under LOCAL SYSTEM
My company has a product that runs as a LOCAL SYSTEM service on windows whose purpose is to take requests for the deployment of small USB driver packages from scanner manufacturers, validate them for security and then run the installers for those, if validations all pass. We have not had any issues for years installing many different driver packages in this manner.
Recently, we received a case from one specific customer that one particular install hangs. (The installation package runs in a separate process so it isn't our service that hangs, but rather the driver installer process that does.)  The same package does not hang if the user runs the installer locally under his own credentials using "Run As Administrator". Nor does it hang on any other system that we know of outside the customer enterprise.
The installer is an InstallShield installer that is being run in silent install mode using the following command:
.\setup.exe -s -SMS -f1<FullPathToInstaller.iss>
Using PsExec, we can reproduce the hang interactively.  By running the command:
PsExec -i -s cmd.exe
We can open a windows command prompt on the local users desktop whose credentials are LOCAL SYSTEM. By opening this windows and running the installer from that window the same "hang" is reproduced. (But again, only on the customer's machines.)
Using Microsoft ProcMon to monitor the process, we have captured "normal" activity of the process on our system and also made the same capture on the customer's system. In a normal system, 3 executables appear to be involved: 1) Setup.exe, 2) chkif10.exe, and 3) DpInst.exe
On the customer's system Setup.exe hangs before either chkif10, or DpInst are ever invoked.
Using TaskMgr's "Analyze Wait Chain" function it enters a wait, forever for an svcHost process with the parameters svchost.exe -k rpcss -p, which corresponds to the RpcSs (Remote Procedure Call (RPC)) service. Using ProcExp, we can examine that on the call-stack of the waiting threads, that a MutexObject is being waited for.
Going back to Procmon, we can see that the last thing Setup.exe did before it entered its wait for the RPC Mutex was:

Searching on the GUID that it queried here, it appears to have queried for a DLL corresponding to the InProcServer for Windows.Storage.dll.  (HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID{75847177-F077-4171-BD2C-A6BB2164FBD0}) Seems to be interested in COM3, makes the RPC call (I assume) and then waits forever for the Mutex.
Doing this same search on a normal run either on the customer's system from a local account, or any of our systems (as a service OR as a normal user), does not make any attempt to use ANY InProcServer, or list this GUID in the procmon log at all. I am looking for any ideas relating to why it is being referenced on the customer's system, and only in this one situation.   (Use of the LOCAL SYSTEM either interactively or from a service.)

Need to add the fact that we cannot test this on the customer system by altering our service to run under a different account than LOCAL SYSTEM for security reasons.  I mention this even though such a test would probably not be useful, since we can reproduce the hang outside of the service anyway.   Seems related to LOCAL SYSTEM credentials, or something under their USERPROFILE=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile, rather than its status as a service.   But how do I determine what that might be?

Do you use PsExec or PsExec64 ?

In this case we used the 32-bit version, as the executable used in the test was 32-bit, the service that we were showing that mere interactivity was not the issue, but rather that the user account SYSTEM (or its profile contents or path was) is also 32-bit.   Same procedure was used both on customer systems (where the issue was) as well as on systems outside the customer environment where it always passed.
